# What does "fine-tuning of a BERT model" refer to?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I was not able to understand one thing , when it says "fine-tuning of BERT",  what does it actually mean:

1. Are we retraining the entire model again with new data.
2. Or are we just training top few transformer layers with new data.
3. Or we are training the entire model but considering the pretrained weights as initial weight.
4. Or there is already few layers of ANN on top of transformer layers which is only getting trained keeping transformer weight freeze.

Tried Google but I am getting confused, if someone can help me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I remember reading about a [Twitter poll](https://twitter.com/lintool/status/1375064796912087044) with similar context, and it seems that *most* people tend to accept your suggestion **3.** (or variants thereof) as the standard definition.

However, this obviously does not speak for every single work, but I think it's fairly safe to say that **1.** is usually not included when talking about fine-tuning. Unless you have vast amounts of (labeled) task-specific data, this step would be referred to as *pre-training* a model.

**2.** and **4.** could be considered fine-tuning as well, but from personal/anecdotal experience, allowing all parameters to change during fine-tuning has provided significantly better results. Depending on your use case, this is also fairly simple to experiment with, since freezing layers is trivial in libraries such as Huggingface transformers.
In either case, I would really consider them as variants of **3.**, since you're implicitly assuming that we start from pre-trained weights in these scenarios (correct me if I'm wrong).

Therefore, trying my best at a concise definition would be:

> Fine-tuning refers to the step of training any number of parameters/layers with task-specific and labeled data, from a previous model checkpoint that has generally been trained on large amounts of text data with unsupervised MLM (masked language modeling).

Comment: its clear that all the above are different stagey for fine-tuning but I want to understand when we are fine tuning huggingface or tf-hub BERT model, by default which stagey it is using.

Comment: @ashishchandan That depends on the person you ask.

Comment: I think I've also reasonably detailed that part of the question: Most people assume strategy 3 (and if you don't freeze anything, this is therefore the exact thing that you'd do with a Huggingface model). I can't speak for every single library, but would assume that most do the same strategy.